# Centos missing ext3.ko

Tags: centos, lvm, ext3, modprobe

Earlier I encountered this error.

`lv_root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY`

Which may be caused by the constant power failure here in our office.
I fixed it by inserting a centos 6.4 disc and running e2fsck from there.
I followed this [blog post](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2012/10/12/Running-FSCK-on-an-LVM-%28Logical-Volume-Manager%29-using-Linux-Rescue-Disk) to fix it.

It worked but after rebooting I encountered another error

```
modprobe fatal could not open lib/modules/.../kernel/fs/ext3/ext3.ko
no such file or directory
```

I tried this [blog post](http://blogforopensource.blogspot.com/2014/03/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-ext3.html) but when I run the `insmod mbcache`, it says that the file exists.

I checked the blkid and the fstab.

```
-- blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="22cda703-e846-4f35-894e-144aed40ebf2" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="W9xhJS-mFKO-Nxfr-DbkI-zPJt-M1Km-kMKe4B" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="71d748c9-e894-4b5d-9c9d-2a93ec6a9161" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: UUID="d988536f-62c8-4a42-8142-9ae6a3292bdc" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: UUID="925b8d63-cd64-42f1-9c06-1f9a4cff4b05" TYPE="swap"

-- fstab
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=22cda703-e846-4f35-894e-144aed40ebf2 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /mnt/ext                ext3    defaults        0 0
```

The LV is supposed to be mounted automatically in the /mnt/ext directory

Here is the result of my `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vboxsf                 37129  0
nf_conntrack_ftp       10475  0
ipt_REJECT              1867  2
nf_conntrack_ipv4       7694  14
nf_defrag_ipv4          1039  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter          2173  1
ip_tables               9567  1 iptable_filter
ip6t_REJECT             3987  2
nf_conntrack_ipv6       6940  2
nf_defrag_ipv6          8839  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
xt_state                1064  16
nf_conntrack           65661  4 nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2245  1
ip6_tables             10301  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  261676  25 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
jbd                    65369  0
ppdev                   7297  0
parport_pc             19086  0
parport                29925  2 ppdev,parport_pc
i2c_piix4              11156  0
vboxguest             209345  2 vboxsf
pcnet32                29202  0
mii                     4476  1 pcnet32
vboxvideo               1352  0
drm                   227439  1 vboxvideo
i2c_core               25632  2 i2c_piix4,drm
sg                     24038  0
ext4                  335766  2
jbd2                   76054  1 ext4
mbcache                 6017  1 ext4
sd_mod                 34952  3
crc_t10dif              1217  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 13282  0
cdrom                  33416  1 sr_mod
ahci                   35561  2
pata_acpi               2513  0
ata_generic             2805  0
ata_piix               20861  0
dm_mirror              11969  0
dm_region_hash          9644  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                  8322  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 70099  8 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

Here are the list of kernels installed

```
-bash-4.1$ rpm -qa kernel
kernel-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.i686
kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686
kernel-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.i686
kernel-2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.i686
kernel-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.i686
```

I tried accessing the volume via the rescue disk and it worked. Other kernels seem to have ext3.ko but not the one being loaded `kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686`.

Comment: Can you boot kernel-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.i686 and then reinstall kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686 ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did awhile ago, thanks for commenting though :D

Comment: Reinstalling the package didn't correct the problem? If you do `rpm -V kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686`, do you get a message like `missing     /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686/kernel/fs/ext3/ext3.ko` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It already worked before you even mentioned it. Post your comment as answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify everything in the kernel package that might be missing or damaged, run

```
# rpm -V kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686
missing /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686/kernel/fs/ext3/ext3.ko
```

The missing file may be in `/lost+found`. Run `modinfo /lost+found/*` and look for a file with fields

```
vermagic:       2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686 SMP mod_unload modversions 686
description:    Second Extended Filesystem with journaling extensions
```

If it's not there, reinstall the kernel package

```
# yum reinstall kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686
```

I would boot from a different, known-good kernel before running that.